# How can I print sheetnames of a spreadsheet using Linux command-line?

Tags: command-line, csv, xls

I am aware of using `in2csv` to save a particular worksheet as a .csv:

`in2csv --sheet "sheet name" file1.xls > sheet-name.csv`

But are there any other tools to just print the sheetnames?

Perhaps there are options with Perl?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`in2csv` from the `csvkit` package provides the `--names` or `-n` option for that: <sup>[[Source](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/in2csv.html)]</sup>

```
 -n, --names     Display sheet names from the input Excel file.
```

In your example the command would be:

```
in2csv -n file1.xls
```

This feature was added in `csvkit` 1.0.2, which is not available from the [official package sources](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/csvkit) for releases older than Bionic. If you’re running Xenial you need to either

- compile the program from [source](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/tree/1.0.2) or
- install it via `pip` with

  ```
  sudo pip install csvkit
  ```

to get the latest version.

Comment: I would have accepted this answer but turns out I have a version of `in2csv` lacking `-n` option. Weird, trying to figure out how to get the latest but having trouble with csvkit and removing older `in2csv` ... sigh

Comment: I'd just remove it with `sudo apt remove python3-csvkit` and install a newer one, preferably from https://packages.ubuntu.com/, or else from https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/tree/1.0.2. The feature was introduced with [this](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/commit/829e176929934bade37cd85dded91df3413b44db#diff-a14fd01737ab485de9d4254287a53055) commit tagged “1.0.2”, so any version from that on should have this option.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that none of the packaged versions reach this version number, so compiling the source from github seems to be the only way to go – in this case, I'd rather *not* uninstall the package version but just write a wrapper function named `in2csv` that calls `/path/to/new/in2csv` in case it's called with the `-n` option and the usual `/usr/bin/in2csv` else.

Comment: ok. I used `sudo apt remove python3-csvkit` , installed the newer one and it worked. The wrapper function is very useful yes!

Answer (score 9):

`in2csv` is the simpler option, but I'll leave this in case somebody might find it useful. There's a nice command called [`xlhtml`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xlhtml.1.html) for converting XLS files to HTML or XML. And once you have the XML, various XML processing tools can be used to do a wide variety of queries on it. In this case:

```
$ xlhtml -xml ~/foo.xls | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//pagetitle' -v . -n
Sheet1
Sheet2
```

The XML that `xlhtml` generates is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<excel_workbook>
    <sheets>
        <sheet>
            <page>0</page>
            <pagetitle>Sheet1</pagetitle>
            <firstrow>0</firstrow>
            <lastrow>11</lastrow>
            <firstcol>0</firstcol>
            <lastcol>0</lastcol>
```

So, for the sheet names, we can query the `pagetitle` nodes, for which [I used `xmlstarlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057143/2072269).

Comment: It isn't available for 16.04 Xenial. Maybe useful to add it to your answer?